# PHP file getting deleted automatically

Tags: php, cpanel

I am trying to upload [this file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php) to my server using cPanel and FTP and it gets deleted automatically.

I tried to creating a new empty file and pasting the contents of Filesystem.php and when I press the save button, the new files disappears.

I tested other PHP files and the behaviour is normal.

Any idea what might be the problem? This is the first time I am getting this type of problem.

Comment: Other than it being a php file involved, I can't see how this has anything to do with programming. Therefore off-topic.

Comment: What a magic! Anyway, it could be permission issue, no?

Comment: @Chay22 The file isn't even running, as soon I upload it gets deleted. Magic indeed

Comment: It looks to me like the PHP file contains some things that **could** be used for nefarious purposes.  It might be a permissions issue with cPanel or your host not liking a PHP file that can `chmod` etc etc ... I would delete chunks of the code as tests .. I'd be willing to bet it's a security measure that's deleting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the symlink method

```
 /**
     * Creates a symbolic link or copy a directory.
     *
     * @param string $originDir     The origin directory path
     * @param string $targetDir     The symbolic link name
     * @param bool   $copyOnWindows Whether to copy files if on Windows
     *
     * @throws IOException When symlink fails
     */
    public function symlink($originDir, $targetDir, $copyOnWindows = false)
    {
        if ('\\' === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {
            $originDir = strtr($originDir, '/', '\\');
            $targetDir = strtr($targetDir, '/', '\\');

            if ($copyOnWindows) {
                $this->mirror($originDir, $targetDir);

                return;
            }
        }

        $this->mkdir(dirname($targetDir));

        $ok = false;
        if (is_link($targetDir)) {
            if (readlink($targetDir) != $originDir) {
                $this->remove($targetDir);
            } else {
                $ok = true;
            }
        }

        if (!$ok && true !== @symlink($originDir, $targetDir)) {
            $this->linkException($originDir, $targetDir, 'symbolic');
        }
    }
```